Search Invoice Number in MS Access using textbox in vb.net
I am developing an invoicing software and have a form to search bills already saved. I want to search items in MS Access table (Table name "Invoice") Related with an invoice number using a textbox(The textbox name is "SrchwtInvTBx") and a button. The database may contain one or more items related with same invoice number. The results should be get into the datagridview called "DGV", and also the items should be arranged in the datagridview in the order of numbers in another column in the database called "Sl_No". The code is below (the same code is used for searching the bill with customer name, and was successfull).
Private Sub SrchwtInvoice()
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(SrchwtInvTBx.Text) Then
        MsgBox("Please Search with an Invoice Number")
    Else
        Dim Searcher As Integer
        Try
            con = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MSDB.accdb")
            con.Open()
            cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Invoice where Inv_ID = '" + SrchwtInvTBx.Text + "'"
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            dt = New DataTable()
            da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            Searcher = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString)
            DGV.DataSource = dt
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            con.Close()
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
End Sub


Inv_ID should be an Integer (long), so don't treat it as a string. Learn how to use Command Parameters -- What is this thing: Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows.Count.ToString)?, dt.Rows.Count is already an Int32. There's some string obsession at play here. Do your best to use the correct Types

What is the purpose of the local Searcher integer variable? It is declared and set but not used.

What error do you get?

Who does the query (SQL) look like then you find your records using MsAccess only?

You haven't asked a question. Please spend some time in the Help Centre to learn how to ask a question purposely. You need to explain a specific issue; not just tell us what you want to do and post some code.

Please read the description of a tag before using it. This question has nothing to do with VS 2012.

Nope. No way. Not good. String concatenation for SQL like this will cause all kinds of unexpected issues, and makes it trivial to hack your app. You NEED parameterized queries for this, and anything else that puts user input into an SQL statement:
Private Sub SrchwtInvoice()
    Dim SearchNumber As Integer
    ' Rather than just empty, check the input is actually a number, so we can map to query parameter
    If Not Integer.TryParse(SrchwtInvTBx.Text, SearchNumber) Then
        MsgBox("Please Search with an Invoice Number")
        Exit Sub 'guard clause... reduces nesting level for the code below
    End If

    Try
        ' What's the aversion to declaring local variables?
        ' Keeping scope small is GOOD, helps the garbage collector be more effective
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\MSDB.accdb")
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = con.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE Inv_ID = ?"

        ' QUERY PARAMETERS!
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbtype.Integer).Value = SearchNumber

        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt) ' Fill() opens and closes the connection for you

        DGV.DataSource = dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub

A final suggestion is searching for an exact invoice number seems like it could only ever return one row, which means showing the result in a grid control is kind of odd. Perhaps add a panel and map the column values to controls on the panel.

If Inv_ID is numeric, no quotes:
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Invoice where Inv_ID = " + SrchwtInvTBx.Text + ""


Continuing to suggest a method that allows SQL injection is bad enough, but concatenating the empty string at the end is the icing on the cake.

@JoelCoehoorn: Please be aware, that Access SQL doesn't allow SQL injection, neither do we know what validation (probably for being numeric only) has been applied to SrchwtInvTBx.Text before being passed to the function. The trailing "" is coding style to signal an intended end of the concatenation. No icing, only a choice of style. That said, your function mimics closely how I would myself prefer to code this task.
